Getting the log "rabbitmq has been asked to start." and nothing starts process hangs there
I'm getting this log and nothing starts, the process hangs there:
    rabbitmq has been asked to start


I'm new to RabbitMQ and Docker.
Currently I'm trying to upgrade the RabbitMQ version, before that I tried to run the existing RabbitMQ version.
The current project has a Dockerfile, so I did a Docker build and generated the Docker image and ran the same in the Docker installed in my windows machine.
When I log in to the container using docker ps and I did rabbitmqctl start_app. I'm getting the log:  rabbitmq has been asked to start and nothing starts process hangs there.
I also use my own configuration for RabbitMQ in rabbitmq.conf file.

Any suggestions on what is being done wrong here?
Rather I straightaway used the rabbitmq:latest image it worked and started without any issue?
